# Installation Error:Collecting tensorflow ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)

Tags: tensorflow

Error raised when installing tensorflow using pip

```
C:\Users\Lenovo>python --version
Python 3.6.0

C:\Users\Lenovo>pip --version
pip 19.1.1 from c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.6)

C:\Users\Lenovo>pip install tensorflow

Collecting tensorflow

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Python3.5.2 to install Tensorflow, but notice that it can not be installed on your environment and you should use base interpreter to install it then you can make your environment and inherit form the basic interpreter and use it in your environment.